# PHP file upload and passing diectory

Tags: php

Hi am sorry but I have difficulties solving the problem. What i want to do is to upload file and then pass the directory but its nbot working the way I expect. The upload goes to a server to a file called 'uploads' but I cannot pass the directory , cuz its what I need, in later decode function:
Here's the code for uploading file am using:

```
 <?php
 // Where the file is going to be placed 
 $target_path = "uploads/";

/* Add the original filename to our target path.  
Result is "uploads/filename.extension" */
$target_path = $target_path . basename( $_FILES['uploadedfile']['name']); 

if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['uploadedfile']['tmp_name'], $target_path)) 
{
    echo "The file ".  basename( $_FILES['uploadedfile']['name']). 
    " has been uploaded";
 } else{
    echo "There was an error uploading the file, please try again!";
 }

?>
```

and then I want to pass directory to here just after $json = $api->decode ( ):it shld be between the brackets I put ($target_path .  basename( $_FILES['uploadedfile']['name'])) but its not working and I dont know how to solve it. The case decode is supposed to get directory of the file which was just uploaded and then decode what is inside:

```
  case "decode":
    $json = $api->decode ($target_path .   basename( $_FILES['uploadedfile']  ['name']));
    $start='{"content":"';
    $pos_start = strpos($json, $start);

    $end='"}';
    $pos_end = strpos($json, $end);
```

thanx for any advice, please help me out if you know how, thanx

Comment: You want the client to determine where the uploaded file will land?  Be careful...

Comment: You don't show at all how those two blocks of code are tied together. Are those samples from two different scripts? different functions in a single script?

Comment: I have read your post 5 times, and have no idea what you are asking.  What specifically is the problem?  What isn't working, and why?

Comment: After the upload is made to the 'uploads' file with the help of the first upload file php then I need to use the file which was uploaded to decode it as its some sort of a code but to do it I need a directory to the file uploaded between the brakets decode (), before i was entering that manually and it worked put now whant to upload a file and get that decoded

Comment: What are you expecting that _decode_ does? You probably want to _encode_ it

Comment: no i want to decode it cuz the file includes a qr code

Comment: Frits van Campen no i want to decode it cuz the file includes a qr code

Comment: @Brad After the upload is made to the 'uploads' file with the help of the first upload file php then I need to use the file which was uploaded to decode it as its some sort of a code but to do it I need a directory to the file uploaded between the brakets decode (), before i was entering that manually and it worked put now whant to upload a file and get that decoded

Answer (score 0):

The way you build your JSON looks flawed. Typically it's best to accumulate the data first, and do a `json_encode` as the very last step. This way your JSON is never accidentally mangled. It may still not be semantically valid but at least you can see why ;)

```
$data = array(
    "content" => $target_path . basename( $_FILES['uploadedfile']['name'])
);
return json_encode($data);
```

Comment: hmm, i aim at decoding the qr code which is in the file not encoding it

Answer (score 0):

I hope this helps:

```
$json = $api->decode ($target_path .   basename( $_FILES['uploadedfile']  ['name']));
$o=json_decode($json);
echo $o->content;
```

if that doesn't work try:

```
$json = $api->decode ($target_path);
$o=json_decode($json);
echo $o->content;
```

Since you are using `$target_path = $target_path . basename( $_FILES['uploadedfile']['name']);` above.

Comment: thanx for that but my php ver5.1 does not recognize json_decode function, when I manually lets say put the directory of file e.g decode ("uploads/anna.png") then its going to decode the code which is in the file but when I put any of the code above I will get sth like fopen function permission denied Warning: curl_setopt(): supplied argument is not a valid File-Handle resource in D:\www\2010-msc\businesscards\QRCodeAPI.class.php on line 121 Warning: fclose(): supplied argument is not a valid stream resource in D:\www\2010-msc\businesscards\QRCodeAPI.class.php on line 130
error in decode

Comment: Make sure `$target_path.basename( $_FILES['uploadedfile']['name'])` contains a valid path/file and check if that file exists. Just `echo` it before using `api->decode()`

Comment: checked that with echo and put  $json = $api->decode ("uploads/". basename( $_FILES['uploadedfile']['name']));    which is giving what i wanted but then i get the following message: Warning: fopen(uploads/) [function.fopen]: failed to open stream: Permission denied in D:\www\2010-msc\businesscards\QRCodeAPI.class.php on line 112

Warning: curl_setopt(): supplied argument is not a valid File-Handle resource in D:\www\2010-msc\businesscards\QRCodeAPI.class.php on line 121

Warning: fclose(): supplied argument is not a valid stream resource in D:\www\2010-msc\businesscards\QRCodeAPI.class.

Comment: It seems that `$_FILES['uploadedfile']['name']` is empty/not set, you can either move the decoding function to your upload-script (where `$_FILES['uploadedfile']['name']` is set/not empty) or store this filename in a variable an pass that to your `$api->decode()` function somehow.